# How to decrease the indent of the gap between numbering bullets and the content in microsoft 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I think I didn't make it clear...

As I don't have the privilege of adding image here, please have a look on the linke [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/knx4jih5l1wnrat/heading_numbering.JPG?n=40292574)

heading 1 and before the numbering i just added Chapter. The other headings are working fine but I dont know how this one become different.

Therefore, My question is ...How can I decrease the gap between Chapter:2- and Literature Review ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "ruler" at the top of the page. If it isn't there, navigate to the **View** tab -> **Show Ruler** should be checked. Then you can drag the little indentation triangles and that should accomplish this for you. Make sure your cursor is that specific line / paragraph.

Also try pushing the paragraph symbol on the **Home** tab to see hidden characters, these are helpful when formatting. Alternatively <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd> is the shortcut.

Comment: Thanks it is working but it is working on a specific heading where I want to select the other same headings and want to decrease the indentation. Could you suggest me how to do that?

Comment: Selecting them all at once is the best I can think of at the moment: hold down control while highlighting. That should let you change them all at once. For the future, define the margins on the first bullet and the rest should follow suit. That or look into the paragraph settings, you might be able to change the defaults somewhere in there.